# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.reset')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I was thinking that my code was right, but it turned out that it gave me undefined, however when i click a button to go to 'List'; it works! it just i can't do it from TouchableOpacity onPress. Here's my code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {fetchDogsAsync} from '../store/action/index'

const DogsList = ({navigation}) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const {dogs,isLoading} = useSelector(state => state)
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchDogsAsync())
    }, [dispatch])
    console.log(dogs,isLoading);
    return (
        <View>
        {
                isLoading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : (dogs?.message).map((dog,idx)=> {
                    return (
                        <TouchableOpacity key={dog} onPress={() => navigation.reset({
                            index: 0,
                            routes: [{name: 'List', params: {breed: dog}}],
                          })}><Text>{dog}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    )

                })
            }
    </View>
    )
}

export default DogsList

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Navigator.Screen
     name="initial"
     component={ListScreen}
     options={{ title: "", headerShown: false }}
/>
```

only the components used in Screen tags will receive the navigation prop. Here ListScreen will receive the navigation prop. However the child components of ListScreen won't receive the navigation prop. But you can use useNavigation hook anywhere in the component tree which will give you the navigation object.  You can read more about it in their official documentation.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/